# How to stop JSON response printing NIL? - Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to Parse some JSON from a URL. I only want the value from Mid_1640m. It does print that but it also prints two nils. The JSON looks like this:

```
"snowfall_last_7_days": "54cm",
 "todays_temp": [
{
  "Upper_1860m": "3\u00b0C"
}, 
{
  "Mid_1640m": "5\u00b0C"
}, 
{
  "Lower_1260m": "2\u00b0C"
}
],
```

My code looks like this:

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let todaysTemp: [TodaysTemp]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case todaysTemp = "todays_temp"
    }
}

// MARK: - TodaysTemp
struct TodaysTemp: Codable {
    let mid1640M: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mid1640M = "Mid_1640m"
    }
}


if let url = URL(string: "https://api.snow.quirky.codes/cardrona") {
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    if let data = data {
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let parsedJSON = try jsonDecoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
                for temp in parsedJSON.todaysTemp {
                    print(temp.mid1640M)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
           }
   }.resume()
}
```

When I run this it prints

```
nil
Optional("5°C")
nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some condition to the loop

```
for temp in parsedJSON.todaysTemp {
    if let mid = temp.mid1640M {
       print(mid)
    }
}
```

note: that's a weird JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use CompactMap to get results

```
if let val =  temp.compactMap({ $0 }).first {
                 print(val)
             }
```